# Region-Area-Point of interest query optimization

Tags: t-sql

My database has following structure:

Every Region (`CountryStates`) can have many cities (`Areas`). Every `Area` can have many tourist attractions or points of interest (`POIs`).  I want to get list of how many Areas and Attractions are there in each Region. If there is none, I want to display 0.

This is my query:

```
SELECT Tab1.Reg AS Reg, CountAreas, CountPois
FROM
(SELECT 
        c.Name AS Reg, 
        COUNT(a.Id) AS CountAreas
FROM  
       CountryStates as c LEFT JOIN
       Areas AS a ON a.CountryStates_Id = c.Id
GROUP BY c.Name 
) as Tab1 left join
(SELECT 
        c1.Name AS Reg, 
        COUNT(p.Id) AS CountPois
FROM  
       CountryStates as c1 LEFT JOIN
       Areas AS a ON a.CountryStates_Id = c1.Id LEFT JOIN
       POIs AS p ON a.Id = p.Areas_Id
GROUP BY c1.Name 

) as Tab2 on Tab1.Reg = Tab2.Reg
```

How can I make this query in just one `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns the same result:

```
SELECT c.Name AS Reg, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(a.Id)) AS CountAreas,
        COUNT(p.Id) AS CountPois
FROM CountryStates as c 
    LEFT JOIN Areas as a ON a.CountryStates_Id = c.Id
    LEFT JOIN POIs AS p ON a.Id = p.Areas_Id
GROUP BY c.Name
```